# How to map clock gate to tech library cell

Tags: verilog, yosys

I have the following clock gate in the design:

```
module my_clkgate(clko, clki, ena);
  // Clock gating latch triggered on the rising clki edge
  input  clki;
  input  ena;
  output clko;
  parameter tdelay = 0;

  reg enabled;
  always @ (clki, ena) begin
    if (!clki) begin
      enabled = ena;
    end
  end

  assign #(tdelay) clko = enabled & clki;
endmodule
```

When synthesising with Yosys, the resulting netlist instantiates (for the `reg enabled`) a `\$_DLATCH_P_` cell which is not included in the standard cell lib file I am using, even though the library does include latches.

Instead of trying to match `enabled` of this design to a standard latch cell from the library, I'd like to use the clock gate provided by the library instead that includes the AND gate, which has an interface like so:

```
module LIB_GATE (
  input CK,
  input E,
  output ECK);
endmodule
```

I already tried the following:

1. Simply replacing `my_clkgate` module source's contents with an instance to `LIB_GATE` and forwarding all port connections. Yosys complained that `LIB_GATE` is "not part of the design".
2. In addition to point 1, declaring `LIB_GATE` as an empty module (as shown above). This had the effect of leaving two empty modules, `LIB_GATE` and `my_clkgate` in the resulting netlist.
3. I also tried using the [`extract`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_extract.html) command with the library's Verilog models, unfortunately it fails to parse (I suspect the file contains some unsupported Verilog constructs such as `specify` blocks).

Of course, I could write a script that post-processes the netlist to replace `my_clkgate` with `LIB_GATE` instances, but I was wondering if Yosys can do that for me?

For reference, here is the "synth.ys" file that I am using:

```
read_liberty -lib  my_library.lib
script yosys_readfiles.ys
proc; opt; memory; opt; fsm -norecode; opt
techmap; opt
dfflibmap -liberty my_library.lib
abc -liberty my_library.lib
hilomap -hicell LIB_TIEHI Y -locell LIB_TIELO Y
clean
write_verilog -noattr -noexpr output.v
stat
```

Where the "yosys_readfiles.ys" is a file containing a [`read_verilog`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_read_verilog.html) line with all the input files followed by a [`hierarchy`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_hierarchy.html) `-check -top my_design` line.

Comment: I do not know about Yosis but on Design Compiler(Synopsys) there is a command `set_clock_gating_style` that allows you to chose the elements to use as clock gaters(and other options). Did you check for something similar in Yosis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition to the previous, declaring LIB_GATE as an empty module (as shown above). This had the effect of leaving two empty modules, LIB_GATE and my_clkgate in the resulting netlist.

This is the solution. However, you have to set the `blackbox` attribute on the module like so:

```
(* blackbox *)
module LIB_GATE (
  input CK,
  input E,
  output ECK);
endmodule
```

Btw: If you read a .v file with `read_verilog -lib` then the contents of all modules will be ignored and the `blackbox` attribute will be set automatically.

You can also read a liberty cell library with `read_liberty -lib` to get instantiable blackbox cells for everything in your cell library.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I ended up using the solution involving `read_liberty -lib` as it doesn't require me having to re-define the `LIB_GATE` module. The solution using `(* blackbox *)` also appeared to do the right thing, but I haven't tested `read_verilog`.