# Superfluous buffers/inverters in synthesised netlist

Tags: verilog, synthesis, yosys

This is another follow-up question to [Combinatorial synthesis: Better technology mapping results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948709/combinatorial-synthesis-better-technology-mapping-results).

This is my Yosys TCL control script:

```
yosys -import
set libfile osu018_stdcells.lib
read_liberty -lib  $libfile
read_verilog test.v
hierarchy; 
procs; opt
memory; opt
fsm -norecode; opt -full
techmap; opt -full
dfflibmap -liberty $libfile
abc -liberty $libfile \
    -script {+strash;ifraig;scorr;dc2;dretime;strash;&get,-n;&dch,-f;&nf,{D};&put}
clean
write_verilog test_synth.v
```

The *osu018_stdcells.lib* file used is part of the [Qflow](http://opencircuitdesign.com/qflow/download.html) version 1.1 [package](http://opencircuitdesign.com/qflow/archive/qflow-1.1.46.tgz).

This is the test.v file:

```
module test (
    input rx_clk,
    input rxena,
    input rstn,
    input [2:0] d,
    output reg [2:0] q
  );
  wire rx_rstn = rstn & rxena;
  always @ (negedge rx_clk or negedge rx_rstn) begin
    if (!rx_rstn) begin
      q <= 0;
    end else begin
      q <= d;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Yosys (version `0.5+ (git sha1 f13e387, gcc 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -Os)`) produces the following test_synth.v output netlist:

```
/* Generated by Yosys 0.5+ (git sha1 f13e387, gcc 5.3.1-8ubuntu2 -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIC -Os) */

(* src = "test.v:1" *)
module test(rx_clk, rxena, rstn, d, q);
  wire _0_;
  wire _1_;
  wire _2_;
  (* src = "test.v:5" *)
  input [2:0] d;
  (* src = "test.v:6" *)
  output [2:0] q;
  (* src = "test.v:4" *)
  input rstn;
  (* src = "test.v:2" *)
  input rx_clk;
  (* src = "test.v:8" *)
  wire rx_rstn;
  (* src = "test.v:3" *)
  input rxena;
  INVX1 _3_ (
    .A(rx_clk),
    .Y(_0_)
  );
  AND2X1 _4_ (
    .A(rstn),
    .B(rxena),
    .Y(rx_rstn)
  );
  INVX1 _5_ (
    .A(rx_clk),
    .Y(_1_)
  );
  INVX1 _6_ (
    .A(rx_clk),
    .Y(_2_)
  );
  DFFSR _7_ (
    .CLK(_1_),
    .D(d[0]),
    .Q(q[0]),
    .R(rx_rstn),
    .S(1'b1)
  );
  DFFSR _8_ (
    .CLK(_2_),
    .D(d[1]),
    .Q(q[1]),
    .R(rx_rstn),
    .S(1'b1)
  );
  DFFSR _9_ (
    .CLK(_0_),
    .D(d[2]),
    .Q(q[2]),
    .R(rx_rstn),
    .S(1'b1)
  );
endmodule
```

Obviously, there are 3 instances of the `INVX1` cell, one for each of the three flip-flops in this design.  I would have expected only one of these inverters and its driven net shared between the flip-flop `CLK` inputs.

In another design (with about 30 registers that are triggered off the falling clock edge), I have seen just one inverter but its output goes through one buffer per flip-flop, which is also not ideal.

Is there a way to get Yosys to combine/share these resources among the registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get Yosys to combine/share these resources among the registers?

Simply run `opt_merge` after running `dfflibmap`.

Comment: Using the TCL interpreter caused an error (`invalid command name "opt_merge"`), but running `opt` instead worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: @FriendFX Yosys 0.5+ f13e387 is from October 2015. Back then the command was called "opt_share". I'd recommend using the last release (Yosys 0.7) or git head.