# How to create a custom technology cell map for Yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys

I have the following simple Verilog design (in `test.v`):

```
module digital (
  input a, b, c,
  output reg q
);
  wire ena = a & b;
  always @ (ena, c) begin
    if (ena)
      q <= c;
  end
endmodule
```

Which models a simple latch with a gate on it's `ena` input. I am using the following Yosys TCL script:

```
yosys -import
set name digital
set libfile my_tech.lib
read_liberty -lib $libfile
read_verilog test.v
hierarchy -check -top ${name}
procs; opt
memory; opt
fsm -norecode; opt -full
techmap; opt -full
dfflibmap -liberty $libfile
opt
abc -liberty $libfile \
    -script {+strash;ifraig;scorr;dc2;dretime;strash;&get,-n;&dch,-f;&nf,{D};&put}
hilomap -hicell TIEHIM Y -locell TIELOM Y
clean -purge
write_verilog ${name}_synth.v
```

Even though DFFs are mapped fine (I tried with a different design), the resulting Verilog file includes an instance of a `\$_DLATCH_P_` cell.

So I tried to follow the note in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948709/combinatorial-synthesis-better-technology-mapping-results#comment71173451_41977369), i.e. writing a custom tech map file to map Yosys latches to the ones from the tech library:

**1.** Using the template I got from the yosys command `help $dlatch+` and looking at some examples in [the built-in Yosys techmap](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/blob/master/techlibs/common/techmap.v),  I created what I believe to be a mapping file, `test_map.v` to use the library's own `TLATX1M` latch cell:

```
(* techmap_simplemap *)
(* techmap_celltype = "$dlatch" *)
module _library_latch (EN, D, Q);

    parameter WIDTH = 0;
    parameter EN_POLARITY = 1'b1;

    input EN;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] D;
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] Q;

    genvar i;
    generate begin
        for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i=i+1) begin:latch_bit
          TLATX1M _TECHMAP_REPLACE_ (  // TODO: support EN_POLARITY = 1'b0
            .D(D[i]),
            .G(EN),
            .Q(Q[i]),
            .QN()
          );
        end
    end endgenerate

endmodule
```

**2.** Then I also added the line `techmap -map test_map.v` after the `techmap; opt -full` line in my synthesis script.

Unfortunately, without success: There still is a `\$_DLATCH_P_` instance in the Yosys output netlist. I also couldn't find any related warnings/errors in the Yosys log output.

**3.** I also tried to change the module name of the mapping cell (`_library_latch` in the code above) and/or the `techmap_celltype` comment to `\$_DLATCH_P_`, but that didn't help either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

After finding [the official Yosys latch mapping file for the ICE40 FPGA](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/blob/master/techlibs/ice40/latches_map.v), I changed the `test_map.v` file to the following:

```
module \$_DLATCH_N_ (E, D, Q);
  wire [1023:0] _TECHMAP_DO_ = "simplemap; opt";
  input E, D;
  output Q;
  TLATNX1M _TECHMAP_REPLACE_ (
    .D(D),
    .GN(E),
    .Q(Q),
    .QN()
  );
endmodule

module \$_DLATCH_P_ (E, D, Q);
  wire [1023:0] _TECHMAP_DO_ = "simplemap; opt";
  input E, D;
  output Q;
  TLATX1M _TECHMAP_REPLACE_ (
    .D(D),
    .G(E),
    .Q(Q),
    .QN()
  );
endmodule
```

...and the `techmap -map test_map.v` line in my Yosys script was already correct, here's the entire file for reference:

```
yosys -import
set name digital
set libfile my_tech.lib
read_liberty -lib $libfile
read_verilog test.v
hierarchy -check -top ${name}
procs; opt
memory; opt
fsm -norecode; opt -full
techmap; opt -full
techmap -map test_map.v
dfflibmap -liberty $libfile
opt
abc -liberty $libfile \
    -script {+strash;ifraig;scorr;dc2;dretime;strash;&get,-n;&dch,-f;&nf,{D};&put}
hilomap -hicell TIEHIM Y -locell TIELOM Y
clean -purge
write_verilog ${name}_synth.v
```

Now the output netlist has an instance like so:

```
  TLATX1M _1_ (
    .D(c),
    .G(ena),
    .Q(q),
    .QN()
  );
```

Comment: Note that the `wire [1023:0] _TECHMAP_DO_ = "simplemap; opt";` shouldn't be needed here - the iCE40 rules have it because they use soft logic to implement the latches which itself needs to be mapped; in this case a cell instance doesn't need that.